# Why return undefined when returning a variable containing a backtick string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

While learning Nodejs, I was able to create a function that uses fs.readdir to get a list of file names and return them in html code with backtick string.
The HTML code to be returned consists of "UL" and several "li", and the goal is to dynamically put the file name inside "li".

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');

function langs(path_data){
    let html_languages = `<ul>`;

fs.readdir(path_data, function(err, list_file) {
    for(let i= 0; i<list_file.length; i++){
        let fileName = list_file[i].split('.')[0];
        html_languages = html_languages + `<li><a href="/?id=${fileName}">${fileName}</a></li>`
    }
    html_languages = html_languages + `</ul>`
    return html_languages;
})}

var app = http.createServer(function(request,response){
    var queryData = new URL('http://localhost:3000' + request.url)

   if(queryData.pathname === '/'){
    let getId = queryData.searchParams.get('id')

    let file_name;
    let title;
    let path_data = './data'
    let html_languages = langs(path_data); // returnd value is undefined

    if(getId === null){
        file_name = 'data/';
        title = 'Welcome';
    } else {
        title = getId;
        file_name = 'data/' + title + '.html';
    }

    fs.readFile(file_name, 'utf8', function(err, description){
        let desc;
        if(description !== undefined){
            desc = description
        } else {
            desc = 'Hello, nodeJs.'
        }

        let template = `
        <!doctype html>
          <html>
          <head>
            <title>WEB1 - ${title}</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
          </head>
          <body>
            <h1><a href="/">WEB</a></h1>
            ${html_languages}
            <h2>${title}</h2>
            <p>${desc}</p>
          </body>
          </html>
        `
        response.writeHead(200);
        response.end(template);
})
} else {
    response.writeHead(404);
    response.end();
}


}); app.listen(3000);
```

However, when a function langs is called inside the app variable, it remains undefined instead of the backtick string I want.

Comment: `langs` doesn't return anything at all

Comment: `fs.readdir()` is async and `langs()` implicitly returns `undefined`.

Comment: If you format the code a bit better you might see that the `return html_languages;` is actually part of the callback passed to `fs.readdir()` and not part of `langs()` - thus you might want to rework `langs()` to use `async`/`await` or to use `fs.readdirSync()` instead and return its result.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. Asynchronization of nodejs is a very difficult part of coding... :)